# Converting a transaction object into base58 string

Tags: transactions, web3.js

So I have this base58 encoded transaction that I receive from an api, and I create the transaction like this:

```
const transaction = solanaWeb3.Transaction.from(bs58.decode(encodedString))
```

How can I convert it back into a base58 string to get the exact same value as I got from the API?

This is an example of a base58 string that I get from the API: (so that you can test it)

```
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
```

Comment: can you please replace the code example here so as to construct the transaction that reproduces the problem originally reported on Discord?  `Transaction.from` has its own quirks that may not translate to resolving your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// Start with your serialized transaction
const base58Transaction = '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';

// Deserialize it.
const transaction = Transaction.from(bs58.decode(base58Transaction));

// Reserialize it.
const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({verifySignatures: false});

// Compare it to the original.
bs58.encode(serializedTransaction) === base58Transaction; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to serialize the transactions.

e.g.:

```
await wallet.signTransaction(tx).serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
const encodedTx = bs58.encode(transaction.serialize())
```